# Linux WebVR with controllers

Tags: linux, virtual-reality

Are there any current of options of using WebVR on linux with vr hand controllers?

-The Oculus Rift DK2 works very well on Linux and with WebVR-enabled Chrome / Firefox builds. However the old DK2 system does not support the Oculus hand controllers  I guess?
All later versions of Oculus do not support Linux anymore.

-Then there is SteamVR, now supporting Linux. It supports the HTC Vive system, which ships hand controllers. However, the SteamVR drivers seem to expose a new API only compatible to Steam supported game engines it seems. So it won't work for general-purpose VR like WebVR-browsers I guess.

Any other way to go?